# How to limit the figure caption width?

Tags: floats, captions, indentation

Figure captions seem to wrap at the page width. How could I make them wrap at the figure width instead? Currently, they can easily be mistaken for normal text.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{center
    \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption goes here.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image: pdf example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caption fontsize and margin on individual figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/caption-fontsize-and-margin-on-individual-figures)

Comment: A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110393/157031) in asked later. The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110396/157031) of that question works well in this case also; we just need to know/compute the figure width and add `\captionsetup{width=<figure width>}`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The **caption** package provides many enhancements: for example

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
```

Reducing the caption to the figure width seems not a good idea in general, particularly if a couple of figures are on the same page or on facing pages. On the other hand reducing the width and maybe the font size can be a good typographical device to isolate them better from the context.

Comment: The OP seems to want to adapt caption widths to the widths of individual figures, not to reduce the caption width by a fixed amount.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @egreg: You convinced me that decreasing the caption width with a constant amount would be better. Thanks!

Comment: I like having things like this consistent. In my opinion,  the eye will detect constant width in captions preferentially to captions being consistently the same width as their corresponding images.

Comment: This line "\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}" will add margins from all sides. But, what would be the command to give right and left margins on only?

Comment: @Nomi `margin=1cm` is equivalent to `margin={1cm,1cm}`; if you want 1cm on the left side, write `margin={1cm,0cm}` and similarly for the right side.

Comment: Oh, okay so can we also reduce the top and bottom margins?

Comment: @Nomi Hmm, what top and bottom margins?

Comment: @egreg as we can control left and right margins using, margin={1cm, 1cm}. i want to say that is there way to control top and bottom margins. Like we should have four margins top, bottom, left and right. can we do this "margin={1cm, 1cm, 1cm, 1cm}" ??

Comment: @Nomi That's the job of abovecaptionskip and belowcaptionskip

Comment: @egreg which is the way to change these locally? Like lets say I want one set of margins for `figure`, another set for `table, another set for `sidewaysfigure` environments respectively?

Answer (score 6):

in caption package guide:

> Only fixed widths are supported here; if you are looking for a way to
>   limit the width of the caption to the width of the figure or table,
>   please take a look at the **floatrow**[8] or **threeparttable**[22] package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\caption{caption text caption text caption text caption text 
caption text caption text caption text caption text 
caption text caption text caption text caption text }\label{...}}
{\rule{50mm}{20mm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hadi Safi aghdam - that works, but it doesn't respect 'width' options of includegraphics. That is, the caption is much wider than the figure with something like this: \begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\caption{caption text caption text caption text caption text 
caption text caption text caption text caption text }\label{...}}
{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{dummy}}
\end{figure}

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered the problem. Sometimes I use therefore two minipages to put two figures beside each other, so not much vertical space is lost.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
     \centering
     \rule{0.4\textwidth}{3cm}
     \captionof{figure}{%
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
       Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
       Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
     }
     \label{fig:a}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \rule{0.8\textwidth}{3cm}
     \captionof{figure}{%
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
       Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
     }
     \label{fig:b}
   \end{minipage}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Additionally to @egreg's answer, it's worth noting that **`caption`** also has a localised parameter that can be set:

```
\captionsetup{margin=3cm}
```

Otherwise globally using the package option `\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}` as suggested.

You can get the documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption).

An example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{margin=3cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{filename}
    \caption{long ... amounts  .... of ... text}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\captionmargin}{3cm}` is the same as `\captionsetup{margin=3cm}` but the latter should be used now.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt thanks, updated to newer syntax

Comment: The caption can be extended beyond the width of the text by using negative numbers, e.g. `\captionsetup{margin=-1cm}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrapfigure environment also like so:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[] {MyFigure}
    \centering
    \caption{My nifty caption}
    \label{fig_something_to_reference_with}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

This will create a smaller environment containing your figure and the caption and then wrap the surrounding text around it.

Additional information can be found at https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Inserting_Images

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This does not only limit the caption width, but also changes the figure's position.