# Too wide figure caption

Tags: formatting, captions

I included a figure using the `figure` environment with a rather long caption. The width of the caption is the same as the page width, which doesn't look so nice. Is there any way to reduce the width of the caption frame?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Her's one possibility using the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; using the `width` key you can assign a predefined width (`0.8\textwidth` in my example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}
\centering
A Figure
\caption{\protect\lipsum[4]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also make this a global setting using `\captionsetup` in the preamble.

Another option is to use the floatrow package; here's a little example using \FBwidth to make the caption width equal to the figure width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{\protect\lipsum[4]}}
  {\includegraphics{image}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Answer (score 3):

The `boxhandler` package is set to define different captioning options.  Below is a screenshot from the package manual.  By default, it makes the caption width the figure width, but you can set upper and lower bounds on caption width as well as define specific widths.  You also see in the image below different caption styles

[image]

And in this second image, you can see some of the parameters over which it gives you control.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner solution to reduce the width of the caption box. This will change it for every figure in your document:

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!