# Figure caption wider than surrounding text block

Tags: formatting, abstract

I have an article to be written with 1 inch margins, with figures of course in the `figure` environment. [...] I now narrowed down the problem to the use of `\abstract{...}`. I use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,authblk}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}    
\abstract{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \ldots}

\section{Test}    
Test

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{fig_Test.pdf}
\caption{This is a long sentence used as caption. It has 
to be so long to illustrate my problem.}
\label{fig_Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `\abstract` directive, everything works fine. But as soon as the `\abstract` instruction is there, its formatting (narrower textblock than standard) is kept for the subsequent sections, and the captions are wider than the text block. What to do, if I do want to provide an abstract for the paper?

[image: Narrow text/wide caption]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please remove everything from your example, that is not needed to reproduce the problem (e.g., the whole `\ifpdf…\else…\fi` section could be replaced by loading `graphicx` and `tikz` without options) and make the example compilable, e.g., replacing the unknown image by an example image of package `mwe`? The resulting [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help us to help you. BTW: Don't understand your 2nd sentence.

Comment: Compiling your example code I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/t63ks.png which looks fine. How are you compiling? I used pdflatex from Texlive 2017.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/how-to-limit-the-figure-caption-width, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110393/too-wide-figure-caption

Comment: @Mico If I would retract my vote I could not vote for closing again. So I wouldn't be able to support your close vote. Because of this, I will not retract my vote even though the reason is meanwhile the wrong one.

Comment: @Mico: So you want to vote-to-reopen and close it as something else?

Comment: @Werner - I ended up re-writing much of the OP's code to focus the matter squarely on the use of an `\abstract{...}` directive.

Comment: In the `article` document class, the `abstract` environment not only uses a narrower text block (i.e., wider margins), it also uses a smaller font. If you use the command version of the `abstract` environment, i.e., if you write `\abstract ...`, you must provide a suitably-placed `\endabstract` directive as well. If you fail to do so, the whole remainder of the document will be typeset using wider margins and a smaller text font.

Answer (score 7):

(edited this answer after the OP revealed some previously missing information)

If you want to write the Abstract using the directive

```
 \abstract{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...}
```

you *must* terminate the abstract section with a matching `\endabstract` directive:

```
 \abstract
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
 \endabstract
```

The `\abstract` directive does not actually take an argument. Thus, writing `\abstract{Lorem ipsum ...}` is equivalent to writing `\abstract Lorem ipsum ...`.

However, it's much better (and certainly clearer, in my view) to write

```
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: Thanks already for all your help, I've narrowed it down to an abstract problem (see edit in my question).

Answer (score 2):

- to have caption wide the text width special effort is needed :), so described problem is unlikely (i can't reproduce it)
- instead `\graphics` you should load `\graphicx`
- the way how the some packages is loaded is wrong, they had to outside of `\ifpdf` test
- minimal working example (mwe) is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{fig_Test.pdf}
\caption{This is a long sentence used as caption. It has to be so long to illustrate my problem.}
\label{fig_Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer was a valiant attempt to address issue as framed in the OP's original write-up. It turned out, though, that the real problem was somewhere completely else, viz., in the use of `\abstract` (a directive, not an environment) without a corresponding `\endabstract` instruction.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for nice words. in similar question many times i have dilemma, what to do: wait with my answer (with risk that nor earn some reputation :)) , or write an answer before the question is clarified ... from question, at least to me, still not obvious, that the abstract is the problem ... as i see, actually is not, problem is wrong comparison caption width with abstract width, which narrower than text width ... i need to rethink if i should add comment about his to my answer ...